# `fold-create-marker` with default `{{{` marker not working properly when function definition contains `*`

Tags: c, vim, folding

I have this setting in vim

```
foldmarker={{{,}}}
commentstring=/*%s*/
foldmethod=marker
```

I want to create new marker using `zf`, which does work for

```
void foo(void bar) {
}
```

when I selected that and press `zf`, I get

```
void foo(void bar) {/*{{{*/
}/*}}}*/
```

so far so good. However when function definition contains pointer, like in

```
void foo(void * bar) {
}
```

I do get

```
void foo(void * bar) {{{{
}/*}}}*/
```

which is wrong. How can I configure vim to work properly even in second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That strange behavior is caused by the default value of the [`:help 'comments'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27comments%27) option, in particular the `mb:*` part.

[`:help format-comments`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#format-comments) explains

> ```
>   To avoid recognizing "*ptr" as a comment, the middle string includes the 'b' flag.
> ```

Unfortunately, the way you write the pointer (which whitespace after the `*`) defeats this heuristic, and Vim detects the `*` as a middle piece of a three-piece comment (Vim doesn't verify that there's actually a start piece before it), assumes the fold start already is part of a comment, and therefore skips adding the `'commentstring'` there.

To fix this, either adapt your coding style (write `void *bar`), or modify the `'comments'` option, e.g. by removing (or refining if you use it) the middle piece part:

```
setlocal comments-=mb:*
```

If you need to keep middle pieces *and* correct manual folds, you'd have to write a small wrapper mapping around `zf` that temporarily changes the option.